# How can I alter a UDT in HSQLDB?

Tags: hsqldb

In HSLQDB v 2.3.1 there is a `create type` clause for defining UDTs. But there appears to be no `alter type` clause, as far as the docs are concerned (and the db returns a `unexpected token` error if I try this).

Is it possible to amend/drop a UDT in HSQLDB? What would be the best practice, if for example I originally created

```
create type CURRENCY_ID as char(3)
```

because I decide I'm going to use ISO codes. But then I actually decide that I'm going to store the codes as integers instead. What is the best way to modify the schema in my db? (this is a synthetic example, obviously I wouldn't use integers in this case).

I guess I might do

```
alter table inventory alter column ccy set data type int
drop type CURRENCY_ID
create type CURRENCY_ID as int
alter table inventory alter column ccy set data type CURRENCY_ID
```

but is there a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems you are actually looking for a `domain` rather than a new data type: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_domain_creation  (btw: there is no version 3.2.1, do you maybe mean 2.3.1?)

Comment: Yes, I suppose you're right. Any idea how this can affect performance? i.e. if I `create type CURRENCY_ID as int` vs `create domain CURRENCY_ID as int`, without any additional constraints? Another problem I have found is that the JDBC spec is not as clear on DOMAINS as TYPEs when it comes to dealing with UDTs ... See for example, this which I raised in the past: http://sourceforge.net/p/hsqldb/bugs/1352/

Answer (score 0):

After trying various methods, I ended up writing a script to edit the `*.script` file of the database directly. It's a plain text file with SQL commands that recreates the DB programmatically. In detail:

1. open db, `shutdown compact`
2. Edit the script file: replace the type definition, e.g. `create type XXX as int` to `create type XXX as char(4)`
3. For each table, replace the `insert into table XXX values (i,...)` with `insert into table XXX values('str',...)`. This was done with a script that had the mappings from the old (int) value into the new (char) value.
4. In my particular case, I was changing a primary key, so I had to remove the `identity` directive from the `create table` statement, and also I had to remove a line that had a `alter table XXX alter column YYY restart sequence 123`.
5. save and close script file, open db, `shutdown compact`

This isn't great, but it worked. Advantages :

- Ability to re-define UDT.
- Ability to map the table values programmatically.
- Method is generic and can be used for other schema changes, beside UDTs.

Cons

- No checking that schema is consistent (although it does throw up errors if it can't read the script).
- Dangerous when reading file as a text file. e.g. what if I have a VARCHAR column with newlines in it? When I parse the script file and write it back, this would need to be escaped.
- Not sure if this works with non-memory DBs. i.e. those that don't only have a `*.script` file when shutdown.
- Probably not efficient for large DBs. My DB was small ~ 1MB.